# Are there any restrictions in the career when you bought a starter pack?

Tags: eve-online

So I bought the Amarr Explorer Starter Pack on Eve Online through Steam due to being only $4. But I am far more interested in being a bounty hunter.

So I wonder if I actually need to stay as an explorer now/am I going to find it harder if I decide the switch to a bounty hunter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The starter pack has nothing to do with your career, only with the ships you get as a small bonus. Just train the skills you need and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, there are no real "careers" in EVE like there is classes in other MMOs. You choose what you do, and what interests you.